# Alternative to lombok experimental delegate

Tags: java, lombok, delegation

I have a a class that implements an interface and  I use lombok.experimental.delegate @Delegate annotation and thus dont need to create delegate methods.

```
import lombok.experimental.Delegate;

public class A implements B{
 @Self
 @Via
 @Delegate
 private B b;

}
```

Since Delegate belongs to the experimental libray, lombok docs suggest that the support can be taken out in the near future.

I can generate delegate methods via IDE but is there an alternative library to generate delegates ? Thank you.

Comment: If you feel adventurous, this is a great opportunity to try [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/#why-kotlin), a Java Virtual Machine compatible language. It supports delegates out of the box: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html